# Getting XML attribute value with lxml module

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

How can i get the value of an attribute of XML file with lxml module?

My XML looks like this"

```
<process>
   <name>somename</name>
   <statistics>
     <stats param='someparam'>
        <value>0.456</value>
        <real_value>0.4</value>
     </stats>
     <stats ...>
      .
      .
      .
     </stats>
   </statistics>
</process>
```

I want to  get the value `0.456` from the `value` attribute. I'm iterating trought the attribute and getting the text but im not sure that this is the best way for doing this

```
for attribute in root.iter('statistics'):
   for stats in attribute:
      for param_value in stats.iter('value'):
          value = param_value.text
```

is there any other much easier way for doing this? something like `stats.get_value('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
root.find('.//value').text
```

This gets you the content of the first `value` tag.

If you want to iterate over all `value` elements, use `findall`, this gets you a list with all the elements.

If you only want the `value` elements inside `<stats param='someparam'>` elements, make the path more specific:

```
root.findall("./statistics/stats[@param='someparam']/value")
```

---

edit: Note that `find`/`findall` [only support a subset of XPath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm). If you want to make use of the whole XPath (1.x) functionality, use the `xpath` method.

Comment: `root.find('value').text` is exactly what i was looking for! thanks