# lxml: Get field after attribute value

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I'm parsing XML files and I have a follow-on question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560748/iterate-through-all-sub-tags-and-strings-from-an-xml-tag-in-python-without-spec/48561670?noredirect=1#comment84308183_48561670). From the below XML field:

```
<enrollment type="Anticipated">30</enrollment>
```

and I would like to pull out the word anticipated, and the number.
In the files that I have, 'enrollment type'/'enrollment' will remain stable between files, but 'anticipated' will not (e.g. sometimes it says 'actual' or something else) and the number will not remain stable.

The code that I tried:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
import glob
list_to_get = ['enrollment']
list_of_files = glob.glob('*xml')
for each_file in list_of_files:
#    try:
        tree = etree.parse(each_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for node in root.xpath("//" + 'enrollment'):
            for e in node.xpath('descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]'):
                if e.attrib:
                        print e.attrib
                        print e.find('type')
                        print e.find('.//type')
                        print e.attrib['type']
                        print e.find(e.attrib['type']).text
```

using this method, I can pull out the type (e.g. anticipated/actual), but I can't find any way to pull out the number. If someone had an idea of the print line I should use, I would appreciate it.

I did look at some similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241700/getting-xml-attribute-value-with-lxml-module)) but their suggestions don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Could you please take a look here:  
`https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements`

Comment: This is great thanks, just getting into xml parsing now so really appreciate all the help. I did look at this, but obv not closely enough/I didn't understand. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing all the right things. Just dont complicate.
put it in a simple way, get the root node using xpath and iterate each child node using getiterator and the value of each child can be got using tag.text

example

```
parent
    child
    child

for i in parent.getiterator():
    print(i.tag)#will give the first child tag
    print(i.text)#Will give the value
```